# Debugger failed to attach: recv failed during handshake: Resource temporarily unavailable when trying to attach with jconsole, but works for debugger

Tags: java, remote-debugging, jmx, jconsole, jdwp

I have a java proccess which runs like

```
tomcat   3400481  2.1 19.3 6323248 1579708 ?     Sl   Feb08  32:20 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC -javaagent:/opt/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -javaagent:/opt/tomcat/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.19.0.jar=9092:/opt/tomcat/tomcat.yml -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

with port forwarding to this machine I easily attach to this process with JVM Debugger of my Intellij Idea, in `catalina.out` I see the only log entry like that:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
```

and nothing is prompted, I just see the debug started and it works

When I attach to the same with `jconsole`,I see in the log:

```
Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - received >< - expected >JDWP-Handshake<
Debugger failed to attach: recv failed during handshake: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

and JConsole refuse to connect:

[image]

```
error during jrmp connection establishment nested exception is java.io.eofexception
```

What could be the reason for this different behavior? `Jconsole` is of the same version of java (JDK 9) that runs the remote debug.

And for now I have no details and don't know, what sort of details to retrieve to solve the problem. If some sort of smart asses know, which sort of the details is needed, they are welcomed to the comments to ask what sort of details are needed to clarify the question. On my side is clear that the Intellij Idea debugger uses the same protocol like JConsole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1616 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.122.97.13
```

was added to fix the issue.

It is very important to understand, that `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n` that is needed for debug isn't the same as jmx remote that is needed for jconsole.